# What is <portal> in Get Cube of PowerBI Rest API endpoint?

Tags: microsoft-teams, powerbi-rest-api

I would like to get call details using PowerBI REST API as per the document available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skypeforbusiness/management-tools/call-quality-dashboard/data-api). As per that I am trying the first method "Get Cube", however, the document doesn't mention any example on how to call it. Further, the URL provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skypeforbusiness/management-tools/call-quality-dashboard/get-cube) aren't clear on what is the value of ?  and from where we can call this? It says no authentication, no request body etc so not getting from where can we call this.

Any idea? please share. Thank you.